# How to save supervisord log files from docker container to machine using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, supervisord

My project runs with supervisor on docker container. All the stdout_logfile files are stored in "logs" folder (inside docker container) and I need them to be saved in the same directory on my local machine. I added volumes, but got socket error. *docker-compose.yml*:

```
  version: '3'
  services:
    web:
      build: ./
      command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --i rest_framework && cd supervisor && supervisord -c supervisord.conf && tail -f /dev/null"
      ports:
        - "${webport}:8080"
      env_file:
        - ./.env
      links:
        - redis
      volumes:
       - ./logs:/orion-amr/logs
    redis:
      image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'
      container_name: $redishostname
      environment:
        - REDIS_PASSWORD=$redispassword
  volumes:
    logs:
```

But I got following error:

```
    Error: Cannot open an HTTP server: socket.error reported errno.EIO (5)
```

However, new supervisord.log file appeared in logs folder(on the computer) and there is:

```
2020-07-30 11:15:07,528 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
2020-07-30 11:15:07,529 INFO Included extra file "/orion-amr/supervisor/conf.d/amr.conf" during parsing
```

What happened, who can help?

Comment: the error is form supervisord, not from the due mounting log directory in docker-compose, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918177/starting-supervisord-as-root-or-not or https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/1183

Answer (score 0):

As Adiii hinted in the comment, this is not the problem of the docker configuration. [The answer to the question Adiii is refering to states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19918243/3324556):

> Supervisord switches to UNIX user account before any processing.
>
> You need to specify what kind of user account it should use, run the daemon as root but specify user in the config file

Therefore you have three different options as your solution:

**1. Change the supervisor configuration to run as some other user**:

```
[program:myprogram]
...
user=user1
```

You will have to map the config file from outside the container to the inside the container through `volumes` in your service in `docker-compose.yaml` or `COPY` it during the build.

**2. Specify the `user` directive in your docker-compose.yaml**. [Take a look here.](http://%5Bprogram:myprogram%5D%20command=gunicorn%20--worker-class%20socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker%20app.wsgi:application%20-b%20127.0.0.1:8000%20directory=/opt/myprogram%20user=user1%20autostart=true%20autorestart=true%20redirect_stderr=True)

```
version: '3'
```

services:
web:
...
user: user1

**3. Specify the `USER` directive in your Dockerfile**. As [per docs it states](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user):

> The `USER` instruction sets the user name (or UID) and optionally the user group (or GID) to use when running the image and for any `RUN`, `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile.

Since you do not share the intent of the `web` container, you alone have to decide the best course of action. I would go with option one though, it's more maintainable.